# Dependency Inversion in constructor

Tags: php, object-oriented, dependency-injection

Currently I'm learning OOP and meanwhile I'm trying to keep the SOLID principles. Is it right to inject dependency (`GenName` - generate file name) on File constructor (for example if someone else wants to write an `Image` class but he does not know about required dependency injection in constructor)? Does it violate open/close and single responsibility principles?

```
interface iUpload {
    public function getName();
}

interface iGenName {
    public function genName($file);
}

class GenName implements iGenName {
    public function genName($file)
    {
        // generate and return file name
        return 'filename.txt';
    }
}

class File implements iUpload {
    protected $genName;
    protected $file; //file obj

    public function __construct(iGenName $genName)
    {
        $this->genName = $genName;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->genName->genName($this->file);
    }
}

class Upload {
    protected $uploadContent;

    public function __construct(iUpload $uploadContent)
    {
        $this->uploadContent = $uploadContent;
    }

    public function upload() {
        // upload file
        return save($this->uploadContent->getName(),...,...);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really a question for code review. For one your code doesn't do much of anything, nor can we even run it. See: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I also find your question a bit vague, given the pseudo-code. The answers you might get could also be a bit vague as a consequence.